# How can I refresh or load JSON to my viewModel on Knockout JS with complex models

Tags: javascript, json, mvvm, knockout.js

I fork the code from here:
http://kindohm.github.io/knockout-query-builder/

The code works nice on the client side. 
But when I try to save the viewModel as JSON and then retrieve the data from the server the UI never refresh at all.

This is the original viewModel:

```
window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko){

  var Group = exports.Group;

  function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.group = ko.observable(new Group());

        // the text() function is just an example to show output
    self.text = ko.computed(function(){
      return self.group().text();
    });
  }

  exports.ViewModel = ViewModel;
  return exports;

})(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);
```

I be added the next method to the viewModel

```
self.Save = function () {
    console.log(ko.toJSON(self));
}
```

Added this button to the view

```
<input type="submit" value="Save" data-bind="click: Save"/>
```

This is the Group viewModel:

```
window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko){

  var Condition = exports.Condition;

  function Group(data){
    var self = this;

    self.templateName = data.templateName;
    self.children = ko.observableArray(data.children);
    self.logicalOperators = ko.observableArray(data.logicalOperators);
    self.selectedLogicalOperator = ko.observable(data.selectedLogicalOperator);

    // give the group a single default condition
    self.children.push(new Condition());

    self.addCondition = function(){
        self.children.push(new Condition());
    };

    self.addGroup = function(){
        self.children.push(new Group());
    };

    self.removeChild = function(child){
        self.children.remove(child);
    };

    // the text() function is just an example to show output
    self.text = ko.computed(function(){
      var result = '(';      
      var op = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < self.children().length; i++){
        var child = self.children()[i];
        console.log(child);
        result += op + child.text();
        op = ' ' + self.selectedLogicalOperator() + ' ';
      }
      return result += ')';
    });
  }

  exports.Group = Group;
  return exports;

})(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);
```

So when I press the "save" button the console show the JSON from this viewModel, everything fine here.

This is the JSON returned:

```
{"group":{"templateName":"group-template","children":[{"templateName":"condition-template","fields":["Points","Goals","Assists","Shots","Shot%","PPG","SHG","Penalty Mins"],"selectedField":"Points","comparisons":["=","<>","<","<=",">",">="],"selectedComparison":"=","value":0,"text":"Points = 0"},{"templateName":"condition-template","fields":["Points","Goals","Assists","Shots","Shot%","PPG","SHG","Penalty Mins"],"selectedField":"Points","comparisons":["=","<>","<","<=",">",">="],"selectedComparison":"=","value":0,"text":"Points = 0"},{"templateName":"condition-template","fields":["Points","Goals","Assists","Shots","Shot%","PPG","SHG","Penalty Mins"],"selectedField":"Points","comparisons":["=","<>","<","<=",">",">="],"selectedComparison":"=","value":0,"text":"Points = 0"}],"logicalOperators":["AND","OR"],"selectedLogicalOperator":"AND","text":"(Points = 0 AND Points = 0 AND Points = 0)"},"text":"(Points = 0 AND Points = 0 AND Points = 0)"}
```

I make a simple hack to avoid the connection to the server, so I take that json copy and paste on the load event and send to the constructor of the viewModel:

```
  var vm;
  window.addEventListener('load', function(){ 
    var json = {"group":{"templateName":"group-template","children":[{"templateName":"condition-template","fields":["Points","Goals","Assists","Shots","Shot%","PPG","SHG","Penalty Mins"],"selectedField":"Points","comparisons":["=","<>","<","<=",">",">="],"selectedComparison":"=","value":0,"text":"Points = 0"},{"templateName":"condition-template","fields":["Points","Goals","Assists","Shots","Shot%","PPG","SHG","Penalty Mins"],"selectedField":"Points","comparisons":["=","<>","<","<=",">",">="],"selectedComparison":"=","value":0,"text":"Points = 0"},{"templateName":"condition-template","fields":["Points","Goals","Assists","Shots","Shot%","PPG","SHG","Penalty Mins"],"selectedField":"Points","comparisons":["=","<>","<","<=",">",">="],"selectedComparison":"=","value":0,"text":"Points = 0"}],"logicalOperators":["AND","OR"],"selectedLogicalOperator":"AND","text":"(Points = 0 AND Points = 0 AND Points = 0)"},"text":"(Points = 0 AND Points = 0 AND Points = 0)"}; 

    vm = new QueryBuilder.ViewModel(json);  
    ko.applyBindings(vm);           
  }, true);
```

Then I modify the viewModel to recibe the json parameter

```
window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko){

  var Group = exports.Group;

  function ViewModel(json) {
    var self = this;
    self.group = ko.observable(json.group);

        // the text() function is just an example to show output
    self.text = ko.computed(function(){
      return self.group().text();
    });
    self.Save = function () {
        console.log(ko.toJSON(self));
    }   
  }

  exports.ViewModel = ViewModel;
  return exports;

})(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);
```

When I refresh the index.html the view is never loaded correctly and show this error on the JS console:

```
TypeError: self.group(...).text is not a function
return self.group().text();
```

Someone knows where is my mistake?

---

The last problem I had was related to the text() function on the child.
I fix this with the use of try/catch. So when the viewModel are new it have the text() function, but when this is loadad the text() does not exist, so I take the value directly from the "text" field.

```
try {
    result += op + child.text();
}
catch(err) {
    result += op + child.text;
}
```

The problem was on the Group class and Condition class.
This is the current and working code:

```
window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko){

  var Condition = exports.Condition;

  function Group(data){
    var self = this;

    self.templateName = data.templateName;
    self.children = ko.observableArray(data.children);
    self.logicalOperators = ko.observableArray(data.logicalOperators);
    self.selectedLogicalOperator = ko.observable(data.selectedLogicalOperator);

    // give the group a single default condition
    self.children.push(new Condition(data.children[0]));

    self.addCondition = function(){
        self.children.push(new Condition());
    };

    self.addGroup = function(){
        self.children.push(new Group());
    };

    self.removeChild = function(child){
        self.children.remove(child);
    };

    // the text() function is just an example to show output
    self.text = ko.computed(function(){
      var result = '(';      
      var op = '';
      for (var i = 0; i < self.children().length; i++){
        var child = self.children()[i];

        try {
            result += op + child.text();
        }
        catch(err) {
            result += op + child.text;
        }           

        op = ' ' + self.selectedLogicalOperator() + ' ';
      }
      return result += ')';
    });
  }

  exports.Group = Group;
  return exports;

})(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);

window.QueryBuilder = (function(exports, ko){

  function Condition(data){
    var self = this;

    self.templateName = data.templateName;

    self.fields = ko.observableArray(data.fields);
    self.selectedField = ko.observable(data.selectedField);

    self.comparisons = ko.observableArray(data.comparisons);

    self.selectedComparison = ko.observable(data.selectedComparison);

    self.value = ko.observable(data.value);

    // the text() function is just an example to show output
    self.text = ko.computed(function(){
      return self.selectedField() + 
        ' ' +
        self.selectedComparison() + 
        ' ' + 
        self.value();
    });
  }

  exports.Condition = Condition;
  return exports;

})(window.QueryBuilder || {}, window.ko);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `self.group = ko.observable(json.group);`, you should take a similar approach as you did on load `self.group = ko.observable(new Group());`, but this time pass the `json.group` data in `Group`

```
 self.group = ko.observable(new Group(json.group));
```

I don't see where `Group` is defined, but you should make sure that it is able to handle and convert the JSON you now pass in, into observables.

Comment: I just check with that code, and does not work. I has been edited my original question with the Group code. Thanks.

Comment: Nop, the error has gone. But the UI is never refreshed or loaded with the JSON.

Comment: Ok, sounds like you'll have to edit the `Group` class. I don't have time to work on it now, but it needs to handle the json that you're passing in and initialize the observables with the values you're passing in.

Comment: Well, I make a few change on the Group class and the code works. But if I don't comment this line: result += op + child.text();
The code doesn't work. The error is: TypeError: child.text is not a function
result += op + child.text();
This method is called on the childs, but does not work, do you have idea why?

Comment: I change the code on the text() function and works perfect. Thanks.